# Search for archived mail by the day it was archived

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

Can I search for an email that I know was archived on a specific date?  In other words, Sunday, 1/19/2014 I archived something by mistake (phone wasn't locked, finger hit archive without me even seeing the email, otherwise I would do a search).  But I have no idea when the original email was sent to me.

Only reason I even know something was archived is because when I pulled iPhone 5 from pocket it thought I was shaking it--unfortunately I didn't choose "undo archive".

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately in Gmail you cannot search for an email based on the date it was archived.